# How to run a script after the system resumes from hibernate (suspent-to-disk)?

Tags: server, power-management, hibernate, powernap

I have configured powernap to hibernate (i.e., suspend-to-disk) the machine if idle. In order to save additional power, I have configured my non-root, data disks to spin-down using the hdparm command. Unfortunately, this setting gets lost after resuming from hibernate.

I'd like to run these hdparm command right after the system has resumed. How/Where to install them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by creating a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d

```
sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_hdparm_thaw
```

Use this as your base:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

case "${1}" in
        hibernate)
                # this is where you put something you want to run before hibernating
                ;;
        resume|thaw)
                # this is where you put something you want to run on resume/thaw
                ;;
esac
```

You will then need to make sure it is executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_hdparm_thaw
```

There are other scripts in that directory, which is where I came up with the base. You may be able to use those for ideas.

Also, those scripts are run in alphabetical order. This is why I chose to name it 99_hdparm_thaw, so it will be the last run script.