# JBL speaker in Samsung Series 5

Tags: drivers, sound

I'm kind of frustrated. After upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 I realized that the quality (especially the subwoofers) of my JBL speaker have a very poor quality. So I googled for it and found that:

[Do I need any extra drivers for the Realtek waves maxx audio on my Dell XPS 17?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246684/do-i-need-any-extra-drivers-for-the-realtek-waves-maxx-audio-on-my-dell-xps-17)

It had no effect in the first place, but after the updates that I installed yesterday the good sound was back! I was excited! I put my laptop to hibernate over night and this morning the sound was gone and the quality was poor again... What can I do?

EDIT:

I have a script that I must run after every wake up from hibernate:

```
pulseaudio -k
sudo modprobe -r snd-hda-intel
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel model=asus-model4
pulseaudio --start
```

after running it everything is ok. It is annoying but I can live with that...

Answer (score 0):

When the quality sound gone, set mute to your volume and turn off mute again. This quality sound stuff happens to me also and I repair it easily like that.

Also you can check alsamixer. To open alsamixer, write terminal "alsamixer" and you will see some of the sound settings.

Comment: Thx for answering, but that does not work for me. I have to run this script after every "hibernate session" (after restart sound is ok): [added to question]

Comment: You can automatically start that code at startup. Just search for "startup" program, open it, click to edit and write your code to "command" place.

Comment: unfortunately the modprobe commant needs sudo to be run...

Comment: A command can be run during boot as root easily. Just search for "/etc/rc.local". 

For example take a look at this link :http://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup

Comment: But I need to run it after wake up from hibernate. Does rc.local run after that?

Comment: To run script after wake up from hibernate : http://askubuntu.com/questions/141702/how-to-run-a-script-after-the-system-resumes-from-hibernate-suspent-to-disk